# Javascript DOM parsing XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am trying to write content from an XML document to an empty HTML page using JavaScript when the page loads. My javaScript code:

```
var main = function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        articles(); 
    });
};

//display the articles by parsing the texts
function articles() {

    XMLHttpRequest().open("GET", "projects.xml", false);
    XMLHttpRequest().send();
    var XMLDoc = XMLHttpRequest().responseXML;


        var x = XMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("article")[0];
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

            var a = x[i].getAttribute("catagory");
            if (a == "hardware") {
                document.write("<p><h2>Hardware</h2></p>");
                document.write("<p><h3>");
                document.write(x[i].childNodes[1].nodeValue);
                document.write("</h3>");
                document.write(x[i].childNodes[2].nodeValue);
                document.write("</p>")
                if (i %= 0) {
                    var summery = x[i].childNodes[2].nodeValue;
                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                    var loc = x[i].childNodes[0];
                    summery.insertBefore("img", summery.childNodes[0]);
                    $("img").setAttribute("src", loc, "alt", "image not found");
                }
                else {
                    document.createElement("img");
                    var loc = x[i].childNodes[0];
                    $("img").setAttribute("src", loc, "alt", "image not found");
                };
            }; 
    };
$(document).ready(main);
```

The XML document is set up with "Projects" as the page tag, several "article" tags with a category attribute and each with child nodes where the content is located. I am not sure where I went wrong. I want to be able to only append the XML file so that the JavaScript code constructs the page each time it is called. So far it acts like the JavaScript  or the XML files don't exist and all that loads is the blank html page.

Comment: You mean JavaScript right? Java is a completely different language.

Comment: Aside from Java/Javascript confusion, I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking. Please ask a question.

Comment: you can't use `document.write` and ajax. `document.write` will wipe out the whole page when used after page load

Comment: Yes, instead of document write, use `document.createElement()` and its ilk.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement